# Vlcj video rotation

Tags: java, libvlc, vlcj

I am currently working on a project that uses vlcj. Right now I have to implement a feature where the user can rotate the video while it is played.

I know there are some options one can pass when the player is set up, e.g.

```
mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory("--video-filter=transform", "--transform-type=vflip");
```

Unfortunately this is not an option. I need to implement the functionality the way it works in VLC.
[image: Video rotation in VLC]

Thanks for your help
klib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API in LibVLC, nor consequently vlcj, to manipulate video filters like that.

There exists an API for e.g. hue, saturation, brightness, contrast and gamma, but there is no API for all of the other video filters.

You can set video filter options using command-line switches when you create your `MediaPlayerFactory` or (for some options) when you play the media via `mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl, options)`. But this won't let you change options on the fly.